# Regex to validate the string in a particular format in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the regex `^[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z0-9]{9}$` to validate the format of a string **AB987654321**

```
if (!( $address -match "^[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z0-9]{9}$"))

    {
     write-host $address
    }
```

I would like to modify this regex so that I would be able to validate **smtp:AB987654321@domain.com**

So the string should start with **smtp:**  or **SMTP:**
Then the above format **'^[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z0-9]{9}$'**
anything after **@**

Could someone please help?

Comment: Then what about `^smtp:[a-z]{2}[a-z0-9]{9}@.+` if you don't care about the domain part. `-match` is case insensitive, so you don't need `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: Why do you need help with this, you've explained all the pieces, just put them together. What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this patter

```
^smtp\:[a-z]{2}[a-z0-9]{9}[@]\w+[.]\w+
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qi0n7L/1)

Comment: @AdminOfThings thanks for the feedback i have made some changes to make it less verbose let me know if there should be anymore changes or  feel free to edit the answer thanks

Answer (score 1):

Match your new string format using

```
$string -match '^smtp:[A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]{9}@'
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Hi94j3/1). As [Theo commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63040969/regex-to-validate-the-string-in-a-particular-format-in-powershell/63042246#comment111480030_63040969), you do not need `[A-Za-z]`, `[A-Z]` will suffice. Note the `-match` does not require the pattern to match the entire string, so you need nothing after `@`.

EXPLANATION:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  smtp:                    'smtp:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z]{2}                 any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z0-9]{9}              any character of: 'A' to 'Z', '0' to '9'
                           (9 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @                        '@'
```